# Why will my file open in the terminal, but won't open when I double click on it?

Tags: mysql, file, terminal

I just downloaded [mysql community server](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). I was watching a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cz3WcZLRaWc) (at time 5:36) and in order to open up the mysql application file you have to open it in the terminal and provide a username and password.

When I found the same mysql application file in my computer files (C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin/mysql) and tried to open it by double clicking, it instantly closes out of the app and nothing happens. I'm curious why can't I double click to open the application? Why do I need to open it in terminal with a provided username / password?

I'm curious because if I wasn't watching a Youtube video that shows me exactly how to open mysql I would have never even guessed to open it from the terminal using `mysql -u root -p`. How did the first guy that downloaded mysql know to do this?

Comment: How did they know? [The documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html).

Comment: Because by double-clicking it, you don't have the opportunity to provide the required parameters to it, and it closes because those are missing. Read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql.exe` is a command-line tool, it's not meant to be double-clicked. If not given any commands, it immediately terminates and closes.

[MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) is what you want.